# How to import another package class by using maven?

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hdfs

I'm currently working on Hadoop distributed File System (HDFS).
I have to modify some codes for my work. 
However, I got a problem to import class from another project.

Ex) Target class located hadoop-hdfs project. I want to import the target class into hadoop-hdfs-client.

I found solution on Google by configuring build path in Eclipse.
However, Hadoop project is compiled by using maven.

So, How can I solve this problem? 
How to modify maven pom.xml file for using class from another project?

Comment: You need to include the "other project" as a dependency in the `pom.xml` and update the maven project.

Answer (score 0):

Find the project which has the class to be imported from the central maven repo and add as dependency in your current project.